# Optimizing performance for searches using onKeyUp, worth it?

Tags: javascript, html

```
var searchText = document.getElementById("textSearch").value.toLowerCase();
if(searchText.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 1; i < 114; i++) {
        if(names[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) != -1) {
        someDiv[i].style.display = "block";
        } else {
        someDiv[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

I will have 3 total searches. Their sizes will be 114, 195 and 87. So a decent amount for a loop to run I guess. My question is, should I code more to make it 'save' the div's that are shown and the ones that are hidden? Since my function is onKeyUp, I feel like if a person writes 5 characters running the same loop 600 times is pretty pointless and will use too many resources in a small period of time?

So the question would be, would it be worth it to do something like

```
searchArray = [];
if true {
searchArray.push( i );
}
```

that way I keep a record of the ones hidden, and on next character input let's say 'if(searchText.length === 2)' have it go through the loop of only how many characters are in the array we created earlier? So saying there were 10 results it'd only go through a loop 10 times instead of 114. Is it worth it? Probably would have to do an array within an array so it records the results for each additional character. I saw a jsperf where browsers run indexof millions of times per second, but I still feel uneasy. What do you guys think?

Comment: http://jsperf.com/indexof-vs-regex-caseinsensitive -- link to indexOf test

Comment: What you should do is set a timeout, to perform your search 100ms after the last key-up event, so that only after the user is *done* typing do you actually search.

Comment: Hmm I didn't think about doing 100ms. I've thought about 300~ish, but I didn't want there to feel like any delay when the person types. Do you think even 1% of the people on the web can type 2 characters faster then 100 ms without doing it on purpose? Either way thanks for being the only person to answer =)